# Let's get critical: Apr 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Biology Stack Exchange](http://biology.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://biology.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [In biosynthesis of cysteine and methionine, where does the sulfur come from?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/15607/in-biosynthesis-of-cysteine-and-methionine-where-does-the-sulfur-come-from)

**Net Score: 11** (Excellent: 11, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What causes skewed lanes in a DNA gel electrophoresis experiment?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/15386/what-causes-dna-to-skew-in-gel-electrophoresis)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [In the lysogenic cycle, does the provirus split from the cell's main genetic material for replication?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/15613/in-the-lysogenic-cycle-does-the-provirus-split-from-the-cells-main-genetic-mat)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Why do people use anti-inflammatory drugs?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/15021/why-do-people-use-anti-inflammatory-drugs)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Does antibacterial soap work chemically?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/15362/does-antibacterial-soap-work-chemically)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [eye myopia power changes with brightness](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/15440/eye-myopia-power-changes-with-brightness)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [PCR enzyme units or concentration?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/15474/pcr-enzyme-units-or-concentration)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Evolution from Mating types to different sexes](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/15634/evolution-from-mating-types-to-different-sexes)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Bioinformatics : Drawbacks of using ORA(Overlap Analysis)](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/15058/bioinformatics-drawbacks-of-using-oraoverlap-analysis)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [Electronic cigarettes (e-cigs), any health risks?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/15519/electronic-cigarettes-e-cigs-any-health-risks)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 6)

---

Answer (score 1):

As I have already mentioned in another meta post, our site has lots of unanswered questions whose answers are in the comments.

To solve the issue, we could either set up a formal clean up event or start posting such questions on chat and politely asking the people who have written answers in comments to write a proper answer. If after some time frame, a person doesn't answer the question, someone else could write an answer.

I want to emphasize that we should start bringing such questions to notice.

Please let me know your views in the comments !

Comment: Just take the answer from the comment and post it as your own answer. You can say that you took it from a comment, just expand on it a little. This is correct behavior on the stack exchange sites as I told you in your meta Q on the subject.

Comment: @terdon yeah..I agree. I have started doing it for my own questions and will soon hit other unanswered questions. Time to get militant :)